# How to map my host's to the container's user in docker-compose using the lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs plugin?

Tags: docker, bind-mount, docker-compose

I have a php dev stack setup through Dockerfiles and docker-compose. I mount the source tree and composer vendor folder to the container. My host's local user `philipp` has id `1000` and my container uses user `www-data` with user id `33`.

In order to map the id of the mounted volumes I installed the [lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs](https://github.com/lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs) plugin:

```
docker plugin install lebokus/bindfs
```

Now I have a service defintion in my docker-compose.yml:

```
  php-fpm:
    container_name: professionalworks
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./vendor/:/var/www/html/vendor:delegated
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - blackfire
```

And for the volume setting I have:

```
volumes:
  mariadb:
  php-fpm:
    driver: lebokus/bindfs:latest
    driver_opts:
      sourcePath: "${PWD}"
      map: "${UID}/33:@${UID}/@33"
```

Yet I see no effect in the container. The folder is still owned by host user:

```
$ id -u
33
$ stat . # or stat ./vendor
Uid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1001/ UNKNOWN)
```

I must add that I know nothing about the internals of `bindfs` and even reading the [bindfs man page about map](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bindfs.1.html) did not enlighten me:

> ```
>  --map=user1/user2:@group1/@group2:..., -o map=...
>       Given a mapping user1/user2, all files owned by user1 are shown as owned by  user2.
>       When  user2  creates  files, they are chowned to user1 in the underlying directory.
>       When files are chowned to user2, they  are  chowned  to  user1  in  the  underlying
>       directory. Works similarly for groups.
>
>       A  single  user  or  group may appear no more than once on the left and once on the
>       right of a slash in the list of mappings.   Currently,  the  options  --force-user,
>       --force-group,  --mirror,  --create-for-*,  --chown-*  and  --chgrp-*  override the
>       corresponding behavior of this option.
>
>       Requires mounting as root.
> ```

Also, I want to mount three different folders/files, but the volume:

```
./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini`
```

should not map the user from the host.

Only these should:

- `./:/var/www/html:delegated`
- `./vendor/:/var/www/html/vendor:delegated`

I have tried different settings for the map options but I have no clue what they are actually doing. Esp. the `@` symbol in some of the examples I found online really confuse me.

E.g. [official docker-compose example](https://github.com/lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs#docker-compose-example) uses:

```
driver_opts:
  sourcePath: "${PWD}"
  map: "${UID}/0:@${UID}/@0"
```

[This user](https://github.com/jtreminio/jtreminio.com/issues/14#issuecomment-490828378) uses:

```
driver_opts:
  sourcePath: "${PWD}/../clients-service"
  map: "${UID:-1000}/33:@${UID:-1000}/@33"
```

What's the meaning of the `@`? Why would I want to use `-1000`?

And most importantly: How could I bind the volume from my host and have it map to the container's user inside the container? Ideally, it could write bidirectictionally, meaning a file created on the host should be editable inside the container and vice versa. Can I, and if so, how can I achieve this using the `lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs plugin`?

Comment: It looks like you have configured two Docker volumes, `mariadb` and `php-fpm`, but I do not see those volumes being used anywhere.  You look to be using path based volumes and not the name based volumes you created with the `lebokus/bindfs` driver.  Using a named volume in your docker-compose.yml would look similar to `php-fpm:/var/www/html:delegated` and you would need to ensure the correct data is copied into the `php-fpm` named volume.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291520/docker-and-userns-remap-how-to-manage-volume-permissions-to-share-data-betwee